# How make many controlParameter to filter GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try to filter the contents of my gridview based on the values ​​of DropDownList. I managed to filter my gridview with a DropDownList but how to filter with multiple DropDownList?

This is my aspx code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connexionBase %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT nom FROM Utilisateur"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceEntite" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connexionBase %>"
                                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT entite FROM Utilisateur"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<div style="height: 350px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" Height="100%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#21e3f0"
                    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="GridDataSource"
                    ShowHeader="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom" HeaderText="Nom" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Objectif operationnel" HeaderText="Objectif Opérationnel"
                            ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description activite" HeaderText="Description activité"
                            ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Entite" HeaderText="Entité" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Debut" HeaderText="Début" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fin" HeaderText="Fin" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cle" HeaderText="Clé" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MAP" HeaderText="Map" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SNS" HeaderText="SNS" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <!-- SQL DataSource avec un filterExpression pour filter le tableau selon la valeur des ListBox choisi-->
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connexionBase %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [Nom], [Objectif operationnel], [Description activite], [Entite], [Debut], [Fin], [Cle], [MAP], [SNS] FROM reponse"
                FilterExpression="Nom = '{0}'">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Nom" ControlID="NomPersonne" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Nom" ControlID="NomEntite" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT : My DropDownList controls (choosen value by the user to filter the gridview)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="NomPersonne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceName"
                                DataTextField="nom" DataValueField="nom" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="DropDownList">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="NomEntite" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEntite"
                                DataTextField="entite" DataValueField="entite" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="DropDownList">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: where is your drop-down-list here ?

Comment: I updated my code on the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your filter expression should be look like this:

> ```
>    FilterExpression="Nom like '%{0}%' OR Entite like '%{1}%'">
> ```

and the expression could be vary depends on your field's data type and your conditions,
for example if your datafield values are **integers** and the condition is **AND** then you could have something like this:

> ```
>    FilterExpression="Nom={0} AND Entite={1}">
> ```

and you should also set a right name on `<FilterParameters>` for Name properties like this:

> ```
>    <FilterParameters>
>          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Nom" ControlID="NomPersonne" 
>                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
>          <asp:ControlParameter Name="Entite" ControlID="NomEntite" 
>                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
>    </FilterParameters>
> ```

Comment: Thanks very useful ! I have a last question for you : if I want to add a third controlParameter, I have to write : FilterExpression="Nom like '%{0}%' AND Entite like '%{1}%' AND thirdparameter like '%{2}%'"> ?

Comment: Thanks but I add 3 conditions (AND) and after, it doesn't work... Look : FilterExpression="Nom like '%{0}%' AND Entite like '%{1}%' AND Origine like '%{2}%' AND ObjectifStrategique like '%{3}%' AND Cle like '%{4}%' AND MAP like '%{5}%' AND SNS like '%{6}%'">

Comment: test your query in your management studio before use it in gridview and make sure this query with the selected values will give you the result that you want, then if the result on management studio is diffrent check all the assigned controls and make sure you have them set all correctly.